# Axis Appearance, matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot cos(x) and sin(x) in a graph. 
Here is my code:

```
 t = -pi:0.01:(pi);
 x = cos(t);
 y = sin(t);
plot(t,x,'b'); hold on;
plot(t,y,'r'); 

 axis([-pi pi -1 1])


 legend('cos(t)','sin(t)','Location','NorthWest')
 title('Plot of cos(x) and sin(x) between -2\pi and 2\pi')
```

I want to change the numbers on the y-axis so that I will only have -pi, -pi/2, 0 ,pi pi
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
set(gca,'XTick',-pi:pi/2:pi)
set(gca,'XTickLabels',{'-\pi','-\pi/2','0','\pi/2','\pi'})
```